# Как при нажатия на кнопку менять спрайт на второй и наоборот?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли сделать это в одном скрипте? Не нашёл как можно сделать смену спрайта на кнопке в обе стороны без создания 2-ой кнопки или 2-х скриптов.
При таком варианте спрайт меняется только на время зажатия мышки.

```
public class Sounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite newSprite, oldSprite;
    public Image img;

    public void OnClick(bool a)
    {
        if (b)
        {
            img.sprite = newSprite;
        }
        if (!b)
        {
            img.sprite = oldSprite;
        }
    }
}
```

Получилось сделать таким способом

```
public Sprite newSprite, oldSprite;
    public Image img;
    int a = 0;
    public void New()
    {
        img.sprite = newSprite;
        a++;
        Old();

    }
    public void Old()
    {
        if (a >= 2)
        {
            img.sprite = oldSprite;
            a = 0;
        }
    }
```

Как можно сделать лучше?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SwitchImage()
{
    img.sprite = img.sprite == newSprite ? oldSprite : newSprite;
}
```

Подробнее: [Оператор ?: (справочник по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)